# How to put UTF-8 string to CloudBoost

Tags: android, utf-8, cloudboost

I used `CloudBoost` for app in Android. So, I can't find the way to put `UTF-8 string` to CloudBoost. 
This is example:

```
CloudObject obj = new CloudObject("Restaurant");

try 
{
   obj.set("Type", "Food");
   obj.set("Address", "Huỳnh Văn Bánh");
   obj.set("Name", "Phú Nhuận Food");

   obj.save(new CloudObjectCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(CloudObject cloudObject, CloudException e) 
                 throws CloudException {
         if (cloudObject != null)
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         if (e != null) 
         {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        }});
}
catch (CloudException ex){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudBoost uses MongoDB which supports UTF8 out of the box. There's nothing that you need to do.

Comment: But after putting, the string isn't expected. It becomes one of symbols.